# How To Change Boot Image In CentOS 6.2

Tags: linux, boot, centos-6

I am using CentOS 6.2 and I want to replace boot image (splash.xpm.gz) to my own.

I know that I have to edit /boot/grub/grub.conf file.

In that I have to edit below line

> splashimage=(hd0,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz

And we have to save splash.xpm.gz image in /boot/grub diectory

but I dont no how to convert image to .xpm format

.gz format I can make with gzip.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using any sofware convert the image to .xpm format and after that resize the image according to your screen ratio and now by using gzip convert the image to .gz format, now the image becomes "image.xpm.gz"